# Spawn continuous bash command and wait for finished stream everytime

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I want to spawn a bash command (`top -b`) that should run continuous in the background and should constantly deliver results. I would like to send an entire output to my front-end via a websocket, every time a complete output is delivered. Unfortunately, one output of `top` is too long and is split into several messages.

Is there a clean way to wait for a combined message and return an entire output? How do I know that an output is complete?

My only solution so far is to let a command finish and collect all returns and return them collected. But this way I would have to spawn my command again every time and I want to avoid that.

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process'

// Spawn command
const command = 'top'
const args = ['-b']
const child = spawn(command, args)

// Data output
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8')
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    const convertedData = data.toString()
    console.log(convertedData)
    // Here I want to "collect" my data and wait until "one complete output" is delivered
    // doSomethingWithCompleteOutput()
})
```

Comment: I posted an answer below... but it is not what I'm looking for, because its too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution, however the script does not recognize a finished output until `top` has started a new output/interval.

I continue to look for a better solution where I can directly see when an output is completed as soon as possible.

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process'

// Chunkdata
let chunkData = null

// Spawn command
const command = 'top'
const args = ['-b']
const child = spawn(command, args)

// Data output
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8')
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    const convertedData = data.toString()
    if (!chunkData) {
        // If no chunkdata exists, we will save stream output
        chunkData = convertedData
    } else if (/top - /.test(convertedData)) {
        // New data contains a new output/interval
        // Old chunkdata was completed
        
        // Emit completed chunkdata with socket.io or do other stuff...
        io.to('room').emit('event', chunkData)
        
        // New output will be saved as a new interval of data
        // We clean old chunks and overwrite it with new output
        chunkData = convertedData
    } else {
        // Adds output to chunkdata
        chunkData += convertedData
    }
})
```